# How can I create a simple dataframe from nested, JSON format API content

Tags: r, json, dataframe, datatable, jsonlite

Using a JSON format file pulled from the SeatGeek API, I'd like to convert the data into a data frame. I've managed to create a frame with all variables + data using the function below:

```
    library(httr)
    library(jsonlite)

    vpg <- GET("https://api.seatgeek.com/2/venues?country=US&per_page=5000&page=1&client_id=NTM2MzE3fDE1NzM4NTExMTAuNzU&client_secret=77264dfa5a0bc99095279fa7b01c223ff994437433c214c8b9a08e6de10fddd6")

    vpgc <- content(vpg)
    vpgcv <- (vpgc$venues)

    json_file <- sapply(vpgcv, function(x) {
      x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
      unlist(x)
      as.data.frame(t(x))
    })
```

From this point, I can create a data frame using:

```
    venues.dataframe <- as.data.frame(t(json_file), flatten = TRUE)
```

But my resulting data is a data frame with the correct number of 23 variables and 5000 rows, but each entry is a list rather than just a value. How can I pull the value out of each list?

I've also attempted to pull the values out using data tables in the following code:

```
library(data.table)
data.table::rbindlist(json_file, fill= TRUE)
```

But the output data frame flows almost diagonally, placing 1 stored variable + 22 NULL values per row. While all the data exists here, Rows 1-23 (and 24-46, and so on) should be a single row.

Of these two dead ends, which is the easiest/cleanest solution to produce my desired data frame output of [5000 observations, in simple value form of 23 variables]?

Answer (score 1):

Your url is connecting directly to the JSON file, no need for the `GET` function.  The jsonlite library can handle the download directly.

```
library(jsonlite)

output<-fromJSON("https://api.seatgeek.com/2/venues?country=US&per_page=5000&page=1&client_id=NTM2MzE3fDE1NzM4NTExMTAuNzU&client_secret=77264dfa5a0bc99095279fa7b01c223ff994437433c214c8b9a08e6de10fddd6")

df<-output$venues

flatdf<-flatten(df)

#remove first column of empty lists
flatdf<-flatdf[,-1]
```

The variable "output" is a list of dataframes from the JSON object.  One can reference using the "$" to retrieve the part of interest.

df does have some imbedded data frames, to flatten, use the `flatten` function from jsonlite package.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'm looking for a flat dataframe of all 23 variables- it seems the dataframe from that pull would still be more of a collection of lists. Is there a simple action to create the simple structured df im looking for?

Comment: @JML, See the edit above to remove the embedded data frames.  As as the first column of lists  it is just collection of empty lists, so I would just delete that column.